# ZFS Pool not known after reboot Server 20.10 on Raspberry PI 4 8Gb

Tags: server, raspberrypi, zfs, 20.10

I am losing my ZFS Pool media-pool after each reboot, although I defined the stretched ZFS pool using `vdefs` with `vdev 01 02 03 and 04`. These are 4x 2TB SSDs.
After importing the pool everything works fine again. Can anybody help?

Have a look here for all the details:

```
ubuntu@RPIMarc:~$ sudo zpool list
no pools available
ubuntu@RPIMarc:~$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 48.8M  1 loop /snap/core18/1949
loop1         7:1    0 48.8M  1 loop /snap/core18/1936
loop2         7:2    0 62.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18775
loop3         7:3    0   27M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10494
loop4         7:4    0 26.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9730
loop5         7:5    0 62.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18679
sda           8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0  1.8T  0 part
└─sda9        8:9    0    8M  0 part
sdb           8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1        8:17   0  1.8T  0 part
└─sdb9        8:25   0    8M  0 part
sdc           8:32   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdc1        8:33   0  1.8T  0 part
└─sdc9        8:41   0    8M  0 part
sdd           8:48   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdd1        8:49   0  1.8T  0 part
└─sdd9        8:57   0    8M  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /

ubuntu@RPIMarc:~$ cd /dev/disk
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk$ cd by-id
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-id$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Sep 24 19:27 mmc-SP32G_0x0a17c290 -> ../../mmcblk0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 24 19:27 mmc-SP32G_0x0a17c290-part1 -> ../../mmcblk0p1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Sep 24 19:27 mmc-SP32G_0x0a17c290-part2 -> ../../mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 scsi-1Samsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123_0000 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-1Samsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123_0000-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-1Samsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123_0000-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 scsi-1Samsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123_0001 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-1Samsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123_0001-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-1Samsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123_0001-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 scsi-SSamsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-SSamsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-SSamsung_SSD_870_QVO_2TB_1234567890123-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06680B -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06680B-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06680B-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06720K -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06720K-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06720K-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06727A -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06727A-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB06727A-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB07228W -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB07228W-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 scsi-USB-S5SUNG0NB07228W-part9 -> ../../sdd9
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-id$ cd ..
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk$ ls -l
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 520 Dec 28 15:19 by-id
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 Dec 28 15:19 by-label
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 120 Dec 28 15:19 by-partlabel
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 240 Dec 28 15:19 by-partuuid
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 340 Dec 28 15:19 by-path
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 Dec 28 15:19 by-uuid
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 280 Dec 28 15:19 by-vdev
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk$ cd by-vdev
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-vdev$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 01 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 01-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 01-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 02 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 02-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 02-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 03 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 03-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 03-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 04 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 04-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 04-part9 -> ../../sdd9

ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-vdev$ sudo zpool status
no pools available

ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-vdev$ sudo zpool import -f media-pool

ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-vdev$ sudo zpool status
  pool: media-pool
 state: ONLINE
status: One or more devices has experienced an error resulting in data
corruption.  Applications may be affected.
action: Restore the file in question if possible.  Otherwise restore the
entire pool from backup.
   see: http://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-8A
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 00:57:14 with 0 errors on Sun Dec 13 01:21:15 2020
config:

NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
media-pool  ONLINE       0     0     0
 01        ONLINE       0     0     0
 02        ONLINE       0     0     0
 03        ONLINE       0     0     0
 04        ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: 1 data errors, use '-v' for a list
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-vdev$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0         7:0    0 48.8M  1 loop /snap/core18/1949
loop1         7:1    0 48.8M  1 loop /snap/core18/1936
loop2         7:2    0 62.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18775
loop3         7:3    0   27M  1 loop /snap/snapd/10494
loop4         7:4    0 26.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/9730
loop5         7:5    0 62.8M  1 loop /snap/lxd/18679
sda           8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1        8:1    0  1.8T  0 part
└─sda9        8:9    0    8M  0 part
sdb           8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1        8:17   0  1.8T  0 part
└─sdb9        8:25   0    8M  0 part
sdc           8:32   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdc1        8:33   0  1.8T  0 part
└─sdc9        8:41   0    8M  0 part
sdd           8:48   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdd1        8:49   0  1.8T  0 part
└─sdd9        8:57   0    8M  0 part
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.7G  0 disk
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot/firmware
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.5G  0 part /
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-vdev$ cd /mnt/media-pool
-bash: cd: /mnt/media-pool: No such file or directory
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-vdev$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 01 -> ../../sda
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 01-part1 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 01-part9 -> ../../sda9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 02 -> ../../sdb
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 02-part1 -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 02-part9 -> ../../sdb9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 03 -> ../../sdc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 03-part1 -> ../../sdc1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 03-part9 -> ../../sdc9
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Dec 28 14:52 04 -> ../../sdd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 04-part1 -> ../../sdd1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Dec 28 15:19 04-part9 -> ../../sdd9
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/dev/disk/by-vdev$ cd /media-pool
ubuntu@RPIMarc:/media-pool$ ls -l
total 2
drwxrwxr-- 4 ubuntu ubuntu 6 Dec 28 10:10 marcshare
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am also just starting out with zfs and homeservers etc.
Raspberry Pi, Ubuntu 20.10
What fixed the problem for me is to export the pool and then reimport it using the ID instead of the pool name. you can get the id by typing just

```
sudo zpool import
```

I think the error occured because in the initial setup I had tried a few different sata to usb adapters so I think somewhere zfs created a wrong connection or something. As a note, somewhere I read its better to create pools initially with the device id and not the dev/sdx name... I'll also be doing that in the future. Definitely with the pi, where because its all plug and play on usb ports the /sdx notation might be a bit volatile... For example I have no idea what would happen if i'd add another drive on another usb port...

Anyways, enough rambling. I hope my solution helps you too...